# Moving files with find + xargs: target is not a directory?

Tags: find, xargs

When I run the following command:

```
> mkdir some_dir
> find /foo/bar/ -name '*.csv' -print0 | xargs -0 mv {} some_dir
```

I get hundreds of lines that say:

```
mv: target `/foo/bar/XX.csv` is not a directory
```

Why? I thought xargs would execute:

```
mv /foo/barXX.csv some_dir
```

for every file that `find` finds. What's going on? By the way, this is with zsh

### Update:

**Update1:**

I tried:

```
find /foo/bar/ -name '*.csv' -print0 | xargs -0 mv {} -t some_dir
```

but then I got a few lines like:

```
mv: cannot stat `{}': No such file or directory
```

although I think the command is moving my files correctly.

**Update2:**

I don't seem to need the `-t` option when using `mv` alone. For example

```
> touch file1.txt
> touch file2.txt
> mkdir my_dir
> mv  file1.txt  file2.txt  my_dir
```

works well. Why do I need `-t` when using `xargs`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you have GNU (`find`, `xargs`, & `mv`), change your command to this:

```
$ find /foot/bar/ -name '*.csv' -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t some_dir
```

*excerpt from [`mv` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mv)*

```
   -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
          move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
```

The above `xargs ...` will construct the command so that calls to move will be like this:

```
 $ mv 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv ... -t some_dir
```

#### Don't need xargs

You can skip this approach by just having `find` do all the work itself:

```
$ find /foot/bar/ -name '*.csv' -exec mv -t some_dir {} +
```

#### Why do you need the `mv -t ...`?

This has to do with the way that `xargs` is constructing the set of files to pass to the command it's going to run each time, (i.e. `mv ...`).

When you run the `mv` command manually yourself you control how many filenames are passed to it and so you don't need to worry about needing the `-t my_dir` since you always will put the destination directory last.

#### References

- [mv GNU docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mv-invocation.html)
- [[one-liner]: Copying & Moving Files efficiently with xargs](http://www.lamolabs.org/blog/2745/one-liner-copying-moving-files-efficiently-with-xargs/)
- [Why does find -exec mv {} ./target/ + not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607542/why-does-find-exec-mv-target-not-work)

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. I am a bit confused though (see my Updates)

Comment: The constructed command is `mv -t some_dir 1.csv 2.csv 3.csv ...` so the file arguments are last. That's the error in the question, in order to use `{}` you have to pass `-I {}` to `xargs`.

Comment: Thanks. That explains everything. What about the second question I had in Update 2? Do you know why I don't need `-t` with multiple files and a directory with a regular `mv`?

Comment: @user815423426 - I'll update it later when I get a chance tonight, I do know why.

Comment: @user815423426 - I updated the question, let me know if it makes sense wrt `mv -t`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the ls command instead of find command:

```
ls /foot/bar/*.csv | xargs  mv -t some_dir
```